# Using ACF on WordPress and some images aren't loading on a page. Can anyone understand this error?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, advanced-custom-fields

My custom fields consist of 5 containers that are exactly the same. See screenshot below.

My code looks like this for each container:

```php
<div class="container" role="listitem">
    <h2><?php echo $container1['step1_title'];?></h2>
    <div>
        <?php $image = $container1['step1_image'];?> <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>">
        <p><span><?php echo $container1['step1_number'];?></span><?php echo $container1['step1_details'];?></p>  
    </div>     
</div>
```

I sourced images using the same method throughout my whole site and have had no issues. The strange thing is that the image in the final container of this page loads but the others won't. See screenshot of error message that I am getting. Line 25 refers to the php calling the image.

[image: error message]

I don't understand what it means.

[image: Custom fields]

Comment: Which line is line 25? (You should probably spread this over multiple lines, so that you will know _which_ of the multiple attempts to access array values it actually refers to.) And make a debug output of `$container1` using `var_dump`, to see what data you actually got.

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: check step1_image in acf if its value is an array and not ID